# Alight <select> in form to the bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have tried every combination of bootstrap 4's flexbox align utilities I could come up with from their docs, to no avail.

Is there a way, in a form like the following, to ensure that the second `<select>` is aligned to the bottom of the `row`?

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="validationCustom01">Choose one. Here we have a long label which causes a linebreak and the select element to be lower down as a result.</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="validationCustom01">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
           </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="validationCustom02">Choose one</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="validationCustom02">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image: alignment]

Notice that because of the long label on the first element, the dropdowns do not align. This is obviously a responsive behavior, so fixing the height or width is not something we would want to do. The desired behavior is that at all screen widths, both of the `<select>` elements are horizontally aligned.

A codepen example: https://codepen.io/cpj22/pen/eYOZPLQ

Answer (score 1):

You can absolute position the select element to the bottom, and reset it to relative positioning when the element wraps.

```css
#validationCustom02 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #validationCustom02 {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="validationCustom01">Choose one. Here we have a long label which causes a linebreak and the select element to be lower down as a result.</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="validationCustom01">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Choose one</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="validationCustom02">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </row>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the text doesn't wrap at specific breakpoints; it breaks depending on the browser font size, specific browser, etc. This would help in some instances though

Comment: You're right. I was just resizing my screen. What if you display your columns as a flex-box? Something like .col-md-6 { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; }. Or just add these classes to whatever column you wish <div class="col-md-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">. You might find this link useful: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Comment: Yes flexbox is what we're looking for, as mentioned in my question I've tried every combination of the bootstrap flex utilities I could think of. Thanks, I'll try that one